# Hibernate 4.0.1.Final case expression not working

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the following HQL query :

```
SELECT CASE his.modelMailId WHEN 0 THEN 'abcd' ELSE his.modelMailLibelle END FROM CommunicationHistorique his
```

When executing i have this exception :

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: undefined alias: CASE
```

any idea plz, im using hibernate 4.0.1.Final ??

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Hibernate test cases](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/hql/HQLTest.java), the case works just fine. Maybe it was an issue in 4.0.1, so you might try to update and see if it works.

What database are you using?